# How to make windows XP service act as SOAP Web Service?

Tags: web-services, windows-services

Assume I have simple program (executable compiled from a C program)that provides text information running as Windows XP service. AFAIK Windows service can communicate with any external process running on the same PC but not with remote processes. How can I convert this windows service to SOAP Web service so that it responds to any any SOAP requests from any remote host?
What are the steps for this like what library to use (not .NET) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magic library that will do it for you, you have to create a Program yourself and expose a SOAP endpoint with the service functionality.

Windows processes can communicate with other processes if those process offer a way for that communication to happen (inter-process messaging, reading system event queues, etc), so assuming your C program do offers a way for that communication to happen, your new program can feed that program the input, get the text information and return it to the client consuming your web service.

If you don't want to use .NET maybe you can use some other high level language like Java, Ruby or Python than can help you get your service up un running faster, but you have to create a program yourself, there's no magic library to wrap a program in and make it a SOAP web service.